# how to create connection , vtiger, php

Tags: php

I have one homework and don't now how to do it. I need to connect with vtiger rest api and show some fields but don't know how to do that. Maybe someone have some code example or something like that? I have read documentation but don't understand how to connect and grab fields. Somebody to help ?

Comment: At [so] you are expected to try to **write the code yourself**. After **[doing more research](//meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592)** if you have a problem you can **post what you've tried** with a **clear explanation of what isn't working** and providing a [**Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example**](//stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). I suggest reading [ask] a good question and [the perfect question](http://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2010/08/29/writing-the-perfect-question/). Also, be sure to take the [tour] and read **[this](//meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/347937/)**.

Comment: Looks like you have a habit of asking others to do your work for you. how do you expect to learn anything if you don't do it yourself?

Comment: Homework is meant for the person in question wanting to go further; this meaning "you", that isn't "our" homework, it's "yours".

Comment: Please show us what you have tried so far.

Comment: I posted code, somebody to modify ? Please help.

Answer (score 0):

you can use the following sample code. for more information read webservice documents!
https://wiki.vtiger.com/index.php/Webservices_tutorials

```
function callvtiger($url, $params, $type = "GET")
{
    $is_post = 0;
    if ($type == "POST") {
        $is_post   = 1;
        $post_data = $params;
    } else {
        $url = $url . "?" . http_build_query($params);
    }
    $ch = curl_init($url);
    if (!$ch) {
        die("Cannot allocate a new PHP-CURL handle");
    }
    if ($is_post) {
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, $is_post);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, http_build_query($params));
    }

    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
    $data = curl_exec($ch);

    $return = null;
    if (curl_error($ch)) {
        $return = false;
    } else {
        $return = json_decode($data, true);
    }

    curl_close($ch);

    return $return;
}
$userName = "admin";
$userAccessKey = "bjwedjndwejndwjnd";
$Url   = 'http://vtigerurl/webservice.php';


$sessionData    = callvtiger($Url, array(
    "operation" => "getchallenge",
    "username" => $userName
));
$challengeToken = $sessionData['result']['token'];
$generatedKey   = md5($challengeToken . $userAccessKey);
$dataDetails    = call($endpointUrl, array(
    "operation" => "login",
    "username" => $userName,
    "accessKey" => $generatedKey
), "POST");
$sessionid      = $dataDetails['result']['sessionName'];
$phoneNumber = "0014242222222";
$query = "SELECT accountname,id FROM Accounts where phone = '$phoneNumber'";


$getUserDetail = callvtiger($Url, array(
    "operation" => "query",
    "sessionName" => $sessionid,
    'query' => $query
));

$response = $getDetail['result'][0];
```